# Использование EF(или другой ORM/ инструмент) для связи Model и ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, архитектура

Доброго времени суток.

С сервера приходят данные их бд в виде XML. На клиенте есть ViewModel и Model.

Model выражает из себя Модель предметной области(и по структуре она отличается от БД).

ViewModel выражает представление модели для View и поэтому имеет тоже имеет другое соединение всего.

ORM(Object-Relational Mapping, рус. объектно-реляционное отображение) делает маппинг между двумя разными структурами(реляционной и объектной).

Вопрос: какие инструменты можно использовать для связывания двух архитектур(по типу ORM для связи приложения и БД)? Подобное я реализовал, но неужели нет инструмента?

Comment: Вам нужен [маппер](http://automapper.org/)?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, вы правы. Не мог сформулировать корректно.

Comment: Ну я вам ссылку кинул, смотрите, оно оно не оно.

Comment: @tym32167 да, конечно). Я впервую очередь просмотрел, разбирался просто, оно это или нет. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что мне нужно, называет Маппером. Я выбрал Emit Mapper для начала.